# How can I know when the javascripts that generate the CKEditor WYSIWYG editors have completed their execution?

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, ckeditor

I am using the CKEditor 3.6.5.7647 on Drupal 7 to turn all my filtered HTML text field into WYSIWYG editors. Drupal does this automatically, but it messes up the form validation. Indeed, drupal still correctly aplies the `error` class to the textarea, but the textarea is now hidden and replaced by the WYSIWYG editor, preventing the user from seeing the effects of that class (red border). I thought this would be easily fixed by adding a script which looks around at all the WYSIWYGs and sets their border red if the associated textarea has the `error` class set, but I'm finding that my script is being executed before the WYSIWYGs are built, breaking it. The only way I've managed to make this work is like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    function fixWYSIWYGHighlights() {
        $('span.cke_skin_kama').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prev().hasClass('error')) {
                $(this).css({ border: '1px solid #f00'});
            }
        });
    }

    $('document').ready(function () {
        var timeout = window.setTimeout(fixWYSIWYGHighlights, 1000);    // TODO Find a better way to launch the script only once the WYSIWYGs are constructed
    });
}(jQuery));
```

As you can see, I'm using a timeout to make sure my script only gets executed once the script which builds the WYSIWYGs has terminated, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to oleq's answer, I solved my problem with the following code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {
            var textarea = $(event.editor.element.$)[0],
                element = $(event.editor.container.$)[0];
            if($(textarea).hasClass('error')) {
                $(element).css({ border: '1px solid #f00' });
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Are you sure `$('document').ready(function () {` is correct? Shouldn't it be `$(document).ready(function () {` ?

Comment: I don't know if one is preferred over the other, but I know they both work just fine.

Comment: They don't use quotes in the jQuery documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should observe [instanceReady](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) event and execute your code within its callback:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( event ) {
    console.log( 'Me ready!', event, event.editor );
});
```

Comment: I hadn't expected CKEDITOR to exist when my script was executed, but it does work after all, see my edit for the working code.